# Hamming code error detection and correction

Tags: error-detection, hamming-code

I am trying to answer this hamming code error detection and correction problem, and I am not sure if I'm wrong or if the given is wrong. Can anybody help? Note: I'm studying this on my own (yt vids) since our professor refuses actually to teach things, so I might have interpreted things differently.

Here is the given:

> Suppose we are working with an error-correcting code that will allow all single-bit errors to be corrected for memory words of length 7. We have already calculated that we need 4 check bits, and the length of all code words will be 11. Code words are created according to the Hamming algorithm presented in the text. **We now receive the following code word: 10101010110.** Assuming odd parity, is this a legal code word? If not, according to our error-correcting code, where is the error?

```
My initial solution is to check the parity.*assuming odd parity, if there are odd bits of 1, it is equal to 0, and if even, it is equal to 1

Parity1 (11, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1) = 111110 (odd) = 0
Parity2 (11, 10, 7, 6, 3, 2) = 101011 (even) = 1
Parity4 (7, 6, 5, 4) = 1010 (even) = 1
Parity8 (11, 10, 9, 8) = 1010 (even) = 1
```

1110 = 14 in decimal, but the size of the word is only 11

I'm still new to the topic, and I can't wrap my head around it. I hope somebody helps. Thanks